# Specifying specific word in word array MIPS

Tags: arrays, indexing, mips, shift

Say I have a word array, wa, if I say:

> ```
> wa:    .word    1, 2, 3, 4
>
> la      $s0, wa
> lw      $t0, 8($s0)
> ```

does $t0 now contain the third element from right-to-left ot left-to-right (would it be 3 or 2)?

Similarly, if I have a single byte, in s0 and a constant 0 in t3, would saying:

```
srlv    $t0, $s0, $t3
```

would $t0 contain the 0th bit (rightmost) or seventh bit (leftmost)>

BTW, if you have an idea, I have to do a single read to get an 8-bit value that I can shift, as how I ask above, how should I read this?
Currently, I do read int, but just realized, the shifting will not work because it is a 4 byte value.

Thanks, in advance, if you can answer anyof these questions!

Answer (score 1):

Memory array is word-addressable.Each 32-bit data word has a unique 32-bit address. Both the 32-bit word
address and the 32-bit data value are written in hexadecimal.
For example, data 0xF2F1AC07 is stored at memory address 1. Hexadecimal constants are written with the prefix 0x. By convention, memory is
drawn with low memory addresses toward the bottom and high memory
addresses toward the top.[Petterson & Hennessey].

[image: Memory pic by Pettterson and Hennessy]

So in your case `lw      $t0, 8($s0)` take the `3` from memory and place it in register `$t0`.